# How Can I set the form background?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-mobile, windows-ce, smart-device

I'm developing an application for Honeywell Dolphin 6100, a mobile computer with a barcode scanner that uses Windows CE 5.0 like OS.

I want to set the background of a form to an image. I can not find any thing like "form.BackgroundImage". Also, if possible, I want to make a pictureBox transparent in order to be behind the other controllers.

Any idea on this issue ?

Comment: Don't use a PictureBox.  Just draw the image yourself in a Paint event handler.  Best done by overriding the form's OnPaintBackground() method.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a picturebox docked in the form or override the OnPaint eventHandler and use DrawImage. Ensure you are using the right z-order if you have additional elements on the form. Do not draw on top of these elements.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to set it like:

```
form.BackgroundImage = image;
```

Are you sure this doesn't work?

You could also take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172529%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).

Comment: Windows CE doesn't support WinForms, so as stated in the question there is no `form.BackgroundImage`

Comment: What?!  Windows CE definitely supports WinForms.